# Отправить post-запрос vue (vue-axios)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Здравствуйте. У меня есть таблица:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Логин</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Serega</td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
<button  class="btn btn-danger delete-event" data-dismiss="modal" 
data-url="#" data-confirmation="Вы уверены, что хотите удалить?">Удалить пользователя</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Так вот, мне надо чтобы при нажатие на кнопку удалить(.delete-event), передавалась первая колонка формы на сервер(laravel). Тестировал axios, что-то не как не получается не могу вписать параметры.

Пытался сделать с помощью jquery (хотя понимаю, что скорее это будет костыль), что не получается:

```
var test = $(this).parents('tr:first').find("th:first");
//
axios.post('test',{'name' : test}).then(respond =>{

return true;

 })

//И также в laravel через $request->name пробывал не катит.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу просто это сделать, желательно чтоб использовать только vue. Спасибо

Comment: актуален ли еще вопрос?)

Comment: Используя только vue - никак. Дело в том, что в vue непрофильные вещи не делают внутри библиотеки, а подключают специализированные. Если не хотите axios - подключите fetch. Вообще же смотреть описание в офддоках: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: А что у вас передается в переменной test?  
`var test = $(this).parents('tr:first').find("th:first");`

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

```
var test = $(this).parents('tr:first').find("th:first");

axios.post('test', {name : test})
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    this.errored = true
    })
```